# Why Qt.WA_TranslucentBackground() hides other widgets?

Tags: pyqt, pyside6, pyqt6

I want to create a splash screen that plays a video file, My project has three python files,

One for the QVideoWidget()

```py
from PySide6.QtCore import QUrl
from PySide6.QtMultimedia import QMediaPlayer
from PySide6.QtMultimediaWidgets import QVideoWidget
from PySide6.QtWidgets import QWidget, QVBoxLayout


class VideoWidget(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        # Video widget
        self.videoWidget = QVideoWidget(self)

        # Player
        self.mediaPlayer = QMediaPlayer()
        self.mediaPlayer.setSource(QUrl("./video/Infinite.mp4"))
        self.mediaPlayer.setVideoOutput(self.videoWidget)
        self.mediaPlayer.play()


        # Layout
        horizontalLayout = QVBoxLayout()
        self.setLayout(horizontalLayout)

        # Add widgets
        horizontalLayout.addWidget(self.videoWidget)
```

the other is for QSplashScreen()

```py
from PySide6.QtGui import QPainter, QBrush, QColor
from PySide6.QtWidgets import QSplashScreen, QApplication, QVBoxLayout
from PySide6.QtCore import Qt
from ui.VideoWidget import VideoWidget


class SplashScreen(QSplashScreen):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        # Resolution
        self.setFixedSize(900, 450)

        # Window Flags
        self.setWindowFlag(Qt.WindowType.FramelessWindowHint)

        # Set the widget to be transparent
        # self.setAttribute(Qt.WA_TranslucentBackground)

        # Video widget
        self.videoWidget = VideoWidget()

        # Layout
        verticalLayout = QVBoxLayout()
        self.setLayout(verticalLayout)

        # Add widget
        verticalLayout.addWidget(self.videoWidget)

        # Making the widget to open in the center of the screen
        self.center()

    def paintEvent(self, event):
        painter = QPainter(self)
        painter.setRenderHint(QPainter.Antialiasing, True)

        # Set up a brush with a background color and transparency
        transparent_color = QColor(200, 200, 200, 255)  # RGBA format (0-255), 100 for transparency
        brush = QBrush(transparent_color)
        painter.setBrush(brush)

        # Set the pen to NoPen to remove the outline
        painter.setPen(Qt.NoPen)

        # Draw a rounded rectangle as the background
        painter.drawRoundedRect(self.rect(), 15, 15)

    def center(self):
        # Get the geometry of the primary screen
        screen_geometry = QApplication.primaryScreen().geometry()

        # Calculate the center point of the screen
        center_point = screen_geometry.center()

        # Move the widget to the center of the screen
        self.move(center_point - self.rect().center())
```

and the third one is for running the Splash Screen

```py
# Run the shit
import sys

from PySide6.QtWidgets import QApplication
from ui.SplashScreen import SplashScreen


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    splash = SplashScreen()
    splash.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec())
```

The problem begins when I'm enabling translucent background((Qt.WA_TranslucentBackground))....

when I disable that

```py
 # Set the widget to be transparent
 # self.setAttribute(Qt.WA_TranslucentBackground)
```

the QVideoWidget works correctly.
[image]

But when I enable the translucent background

```py
    # Set the widget to be transparent
    self.setAttribute(Qt.WA_TranslucentBackground)
```

the splash screen become like the image below
[image]

But I want the background translucensy because I want to make margins transparent.
What should I do?